# Passing table and column name to function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to write a function which performs zonal statistics in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.
I have a table of vector circles and want the mean value of a raster within each of those circles. I have code that works fine but want to write it as a separate function so I can re-use it with different rasters without repeating the code each time.
My problem is that when I run it I get the error message *ERROR too few arguments for format ()* from the line calling the function. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? It's probably really obvious I just can't see it.

Here's my function.

```
    create or replace function mean_zonal_stats(rast_name text, col_name text)

    returns void as $$
    begin
        drop table if exists temp_t;             
        execute format ('create table temp_t as '
                'select id, geom, (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(raster.rast,1,geom,true),1,true)).mean as %I '
                'from %I as raster '
                'inner join circles on ST_Intersects(geom, rast) '
                'group by id, geom', col_name, rast_name);

        -- copy results to circles
        execute format ('alter table circles add column %I decimal',col_name);
        execute format ('update circles set %I = (select round(%I::numeric,4) from temp_t '
                'where circles.id = temp_t.id)',col_name);
    end; $$
    language plpgsql;
```

I'm calling it from the following code block. "Circles" is the main table storing the geometry and has a fixed name so I don't need to update that dynamically.

```
    do
    $$
    declare
        raster_name text;
        column_name text;
    
    begin
        raster_name = 'ndvi1';  
        column_name = 'mean_value_ndvi1';
        perform mean_zonal_stats(raster_name,column_name);

    end$$;
```

My various raster names don't follow a pattern so I need to set the variable raster_name and column_name each time I call it.

Comment: the last format has 2 `%I` but only one argument

Comment: Without positional argument pattern, PG assumes one argument per wildcard - use `%1$I` where `1$` (`1`) refers to the position of the argument list passed to the function.

Comment: D'oh. Thanks both. I've stared at that and not been able to see it at all. Yes, I needed the %1$ adding in. All sorted now. Runs perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Straight-up database questions are likely better researched at [dba.se].